# Common query for multiple similar entity types in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a scenario where I have 3 types of products in a database and all products have their own separate tables (e.g. `Product1`, `Product2` and `Product3`). Almost all of the product tables have the same schema. I have the requirement to get separate types of products in different tables.

I currently have 3 methods to get the products, one for each product type:

```
public List<Product1> GetProduct1Data() {
    //....
    context.Product1.Where(..).Tolist();
}

public List<Product2> GetProduct2Data() {
    //....
    context.Product2.Where(..).Tolist();
}

public List<Product3> GetProduct3Data() {
    //....
    context.Product3.Where(..).Tolist();
}
```

While calling products I have a WebApi method which accepts product type and calls the respective methods:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProducts(ProductType product)
{ 
    ///....
    // Ii have to call repositories according to product parameter
}
```

Does Entity Framework have any way that I can select a table with only one method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a generic method with an interface constraint.

When you have these auto-generated POCO classes:

```
public partial class Product1 {
    public string Column1 {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Column2 {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public partial class Product2 {
    public string Column1 {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Column2 {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public partial class Product3 {
    public string Column1 {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Column2 {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

You create an interface for the properties the entity classes have in common...

```
interface IProduct {
    string Column1 {
        get;
        set;
    }

    string Column2 {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

...which you apply to your generated classes (in new code files - the classes are partial to allow you to do that):

```
partial class Product1 : IProduct {};
partial class Product2 : IProduct {};
partial class Product3 : IProduct {};
```

Now you can create a generic method for your query. You can make it an extension method to apply it to your `DbSet`s:

```
static class ProductExtensions {
    public static List<T> GetProducts<T>(this DbSet<T> products)
        where T : IProduct {

        var productQry =
            from product in products
            where product.Column1 == "Example"
            select product;
        return productQry.ToList();
    }
}
```

You can use this extension method on your `DbSet`s:

```
List<Product1> product1List = context.Product1s.GetProducts();
List<Product2> product2List = context.Product2s.GetProducts();
List<Product3> product3List = context.Product3s.GetProducts();
```

The only restriction that you have is that the columns in your tables really need to have the same name and type. EF does not recognize explicit interface implementations. On the other hand, the tables don't have to be completely identical. You can define an interface for a part of the columns (which have to match) and the rest can be different.

Comment: can you please elaborate extension method please?

Comment: basically i am confuse with     "from product in products" line do you mean by    " from product in source"? other then that it's perfectly fine @sefe

Answer (score 2):

Provided answer is the most elegant solution, but I am thinking an alternative: mapping to a view.

If the various products tables are mainly used for reading and in an aggregated manner (read from many types at once), it may be convenient to create a view over all of them and map to it:

```
CREATE VIEW ProductAggregated
AS
SELECT 1 AS ProdTypeId, ProdId AS ProductId, Name AS ProductName          -- other product columns may come here
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ProdTypeId, Id AS ProductId, ProdName AS ProductName          -- different columns names may be harmonized with aliasing
-- other product types table may be entered here
```

Map a POCO to the view:

```
public class ProductAggregated
{
    public int ProdTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    // other properties come here
}
```

Relevant product types may be defined into an enum:

```
public enum ProdType
{
    None = 0,                   -- as default value, if needed
    ProdType1 = 1,
    ProdType2 = 2
    ProdType3 = 3
}
```

You may easily select products based on natural conditions:

```
// all products
var allProducts = context.ProductAggregateds.ToList();

// all products of certain types
var types = new List<int> { (int)ProdType.ProdType1, (int)ProdType.ProdType3 };
var only13Products = context.ProductAggregateds
    .Where(p => types.Contains(p.ProductTypeId)
    .ToList();
```

If a new product type is created and the application does not deal with its specific columns, just add an UNION ALL to the view and everything should work fine.

Comment: You can map to a view. The disadvantage is that when you map your entity class directly to the view, you can't add navigation properties. When you map to a table which you turn into a view, you need to repeat that manual effort everytime you update the modle from the DB,

Comment: That is correct. Also, in the database first approach, the designer cannot figure out by itself which is the key and outputs an warning. Clearly, your solution is better (personally, I like C# approaches over SQL ones), but if there are many product types and they are irrelevant for the service layer in C#, this might be considered. It also allows an "interface like" usage in SQL.

Comment: @Alexei: You're right about the warning. But it only appears (and stays until the project is closed) when you update the model. When you reopen the project and compile the warning will be gone.

Comment: @Sefe - for me it stays forever. Reopening the solution will hide it until a build is performed. Manually specifying the key fixes it until entity is refreshed.