# Conditionally select between different DbContext.DbSet (as template-parameter)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

Scenario: I have an existing database where I operate on. I transform data and map them into new tables.
To easy validation of these transformations I need to put them into seperate tables (prefixed with *Test_*).
But I still need the functionality of the production-layout.
Therefore I somehow must give the *target-table* as a template parameter to the transform-task (`Process()`).

```
// existing Models
public virtual class DataRecord1
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
public virtual class DataRecord2
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

// new Tables
public virtual class Test_DataRecord1 : DataRecord1
{}
public virtual class Test_DataRecord2 : DataRecord2
{}

public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<DataRecord1> DataRecord1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DataRecord2> DataRecord2 { get; set; }
    // Test
    public virtual DbSet<Test_DataRecord1> Test_DataRecord1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Test_DataRecord2> Test_DataRecord2 { get; set; }
}
```

The transformation might use multiple context-instances across multiple functions, so passing the context is not an option.

```
public class ProcessTask
{
        // transform data
    public void Process()
    {
        using( var context = new DatabaseContext() )
        {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            var data1 = context.DataRecord2
                .Where( ... )
                .ToList();
            var data2 = context.DataRecord1
                .Where( ... )
                .ToList();

            // operate and transform data 

            context.DataRecord1.AddRange( ... );

            context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        this.SubProcess();
    }

    private void SubProcess()
    {
        using( var context1 = new DatabaseContext() )
        using( var context2 = new DatabaseContext() )
        {
            // operate on the data
        }
    }
}

public static class Main()
{
    // current use:
    new ProcessTask().Process();
    // new functionality:
    new ProcessTask<Mode.Test>.Process(); // somehow change the task, so that Test_DataRecord is used
}
```

**How do I modify `Process()` to conditionally select between `DataRecords` and `Test_DataRecords`?**

Comment: Giving `DatabaseContext` as function-argument doesn't help, as `Process()` may use multiple instances of the DB-Context or call other functions

Comment: You don't provide any details on how you're actually determining whether you want the `Test_DataRecord` or the regular `DataRecord`?

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize your `Process` method with a selector method:

```
private void Process<T>(Func<DatabaseContext , DbSet<T>> selector)
    where T : DataRecord
{
    using( var context = new DatabaseContext() )
    {
        var dataRecords = selector(context);
        context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        var data = dataRecords
            .Where( ... )
            .ToList();

        // operate and transform data 

        dataRecords.AddRange( ... );

        context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You can call this method for your different sets:

```
public void ProcessDataRecord()
{
    Process(context => context.DataRecords);
}


public void ProcessTest_DataRecord()
{
    Process(context => context.Test_DataRecords);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to *not* specify (or only once for all different `IProcessTask` implementations) the template-constraint? because I might use multiple `DataRecord`-classes and ther *Test_* counterparts in the function

Comment: @user5997884: You can just paramterize your query and `AddRange` part in a method and call it multiple times from within `Process`. That way you only have to create the context once and use only one transaction. At some point you have to split the queries though, since you have multiple DbSets.

Comment: @user5997884: You can define an interface and use it as a constraint. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339968/one-query-for-multiple-similar-tables-in-entity-framework/41340270#41340270

Comment: Yes, but this isn't comfortable in an existing code base, as I then need to create interfaces for a few thousands properties in all the classes. Also I need to keep them up to date when changing the EF-models, dont I? I guess there is no *easy and fast* way of doing this then

Comment: You don't need the interface here because of your base class.