# Inheritance in DbSet<T> EntityFramework for similar tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to do Inheritance for similar tables.

For example suppose we have two tables: `Teachers` and `Students` both of them can be derived from a base class `Human`.

Is it possible to write a common task and avoid repeat code using EntityFramework? a function like this which works for `DbSet<Student>` and `DbSet<Teacher>`:

```
void IncreaseAge(DbSet<Human> humans, int id)
{
   //
}
```

and more important, a generic add function to db, pseudo code:

```
void AddHuman({...}, string name, int age)
{
   // add a human to related table
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339968/common-query-for-multiple-similar-entity-types-in-entity-framework/41340270#41340270

Comment: Increase Age, should work on a Human and Not a DBSet,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Extension with a Generic parameter:

```
void IncreaseAge<T>(DbSet<T> entities, int id) where T: Human
{
   var current = entities.Find(id);
   current.Age++;
   // SaveChanges() in the context
}
```

If your Student is inheriting Age property from Human class. This code should work perfectly.

### Edited

Also, you can apply the same technique for the add

```
void Insert<T>(DbSet<T> entities, string name, int age) where T: new(), Human
{
   entities.Add(new T{ Name = name, Age = age });
   // SaveChanges() in the context
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I updated my question, what about generic add to db? your code doesn't work for add.

Comment: @mojtaba357 First, you shouldn't modify the question after it has been answered, but post another question. Second, you can't say that a code doesn't work simply because you didn't provide any code (even for the original question).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have read about the [various strategies](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) when using inheritance in Entity Framework. The nice thing about entity framework is that it hides the used inheritance strategy.

As the three inheritance strategies are described in the link, there is no need to describe the fluent API needed for this. I'll only write the classes you'll end up with and how to do queries on Students, Teachers and the common base class Persons.

Furthermore I'll describe some considerations needed to properly select the correct inheritance strategy.

So you have `Student` and `Teachers`, both derived from `Person`.

```
abstract class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set}
    public Gender Gender {get; set;}
    public DateTime Birthday {get; set;}
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

And the DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

Now whenever you have an IQueryable of Teachers or Students you can also use all properties of Person, without doing something special.

```
var maleTeachers = myDbContext.Teachers
    .Where(teacher => teacher.Gender == Gender.Male);
var youngStudents = myDbcontext.Students
    .Where(student => student.Birthday > new Datetime(2000, 1, 1);
```

If you have to query all Persons, you'll have to Concatenate the Students and the Teachers. In baby steps:

```
IQueryable<Person> teachers = myDbcontext.Teachers.Cast<Person>();
IQueryable<Person> students = myDbContext.Students.Cast<Person>();
IQueryable<Person> allPersons = teachers.Concat(students);
var result = allPersons.Where(person => ...)
     .Select(person => ...)
     ... etc
```

Of course this can be done in one statement.

### Decide which inheritance strategy to use

When deciding on the inheritance strategy, keep in mind what kind of queries you'll do most:

- Query Teachers who ... or Query Students who ...
- Query Persons that ...

If you do the first most often, then consider [Table per concrete class (TPC).](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) You'll have two tables, one for students and one for teachers. The Person properties are in the same table. So table Students will have Person columns; table Teachers will also have Person columns.

The advantage is that if you ask for "Students who ...", only one table is involved. a join won't be necessary.

The disadvantage is that if you ask for "Persons that ...", the Teachers and Students tables need to be concatenated.

If you will be querying Persons more often, consider [creating Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt). The result will be three tables with foreign keys: Teachers, Persons, Students. When asking for Persons, only one table is involved. However, when asking for Teachers we always need to join two tables.

Even if you opt for the best inheritance strategy because those are the kind of queries you perform most often you might sometimes have to do the other type of queries.

### TPC: Table per concrete class

You choose this if you mostly ask for Teachers that ... or Students who ... You'll end up with two tables: one for Students, and one for Teachers. There will be no Persons table.

If you have to do an occasional Person query you'll have to concatenate the two sequences. This is in baby steps:

```
IQueryable<Person> teachers = myDbcontext.Teachers.Cast<Person>();
IQueryable<Person> students = myDbContext.Students.Cast<Person>();
IQueryable<Person> allPersons = teachers.Concat(students);
var result = allPersons.Where(person => ...)
     .Select(person => ...)
     ... etc
```

Of course this can be done in one statement.

If you have to do this more often consider adding a prperty to your DbContext class that does this for you:

```
class MyDbcontext : Dbcontext
{
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}

    public IQueryable<Person> Persons
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Teachers.Cast<Person>()
            .Concat(this.Students.Cast<Person>());
        }
    }
}
```

Usage will be:

```
using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
     IQueryable<Person> females = myDbcontext.Persons
        .Where(person => person.Gender == Gender.Female);
}
```

If you don't want to pollute your Dbcontext, consider creating an extension function that does the same. See [extension functions demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static class MyDbContextExtensions
{
    IQueryable<Person> Persons(this MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        return dbContext.Teachers.Cast<Person>()
            .Concat(dbContext.Students.Cast<Person>());
    }
}
```

### TPT: table per type

You'll end up with three tables, Students, Teachers, Persons. Students and Teachers will have a foreign key to the Persons they are.

You can query Persons directly using the DbSet. On the other hand, if you want only Teachers who..., you'll just access the DbSet. As soon as you use one of the inherited Person properties, Entity framework will automatically do the join for you. You won't see this in the code. So even though you don't do a join, internally two tables are involved, which might be less efficient.

So be careful which inheritance strategy you choose.

Comment: This answer does not show anything useful, Why don't you show them how to work with an IQueryable<Person> or write a generic method that works with an IQueryable<T> where T : Person

Comment: The question was: Is it possible to write a common task and avoid repeat code using EntityFramework? I answered that in my first line. But you have to consider which type of inheritance you will be using to keep your code efficient. Why is that not useful?

Answer (score 1):

A DbSet represents *all* the entities.  You'd normally not pass it to a function.  Instead consider a method like this in your DbContext:

```
    public void IncreaseAge(IQueryable<Human> humans) 
    {            
        foreach( var h in humans)
        {
            h.Age++;
        }
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

Then you can pass in an query that specifies a set of teachers or students you'd like to operate on.  EG:

```
     db.IncreaseAge(db.Teachers.Where(t => t.Age == 47));
```

Comment: This statement is wrong,  `db.IncreaseAge()` increase age is not defined on the DB

Comment: @johnny5 "increase age is not defined on the DB " sure it is, because that's where I put it.  But it could be elsewhere.  If outside of the DbContext, it would probably take (or return) IList<Human> as you'd need the collection after the call.

Comment: Or just extension method `IncreaseAge(this IQueryable<Human> humans)` ... then it looks like `db.Teachers.Where(t => t.Age == 47).IncreaseAge();`