# Entity Framework, Method with any entity as parameter (How to make code more generic)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generic-programming

I have a method that takes a context and entity object as parameters.
This method should be able to determine if a common property (COID in my code) of any class(table) has a value.

I can't find a way to rewrite this code so it is more generic, and at the moment I am checking the type of each entity passed to the method.

```
    public async static Task<bool> IsCOIDAssigned(ProjectEntities _context, object _entity)
    {
        var bSuccess = false;

        //First type to check
        if (_entity is tblLine)
        {
            var _line = _entity as tblLine;
            await _context.Entry(_entity).ReloadAsync().ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if (!x.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var query = from c in _context.tblLines
                                where c.ID.Equals(_line.ID)
                                select c;
                    if(query.Single().COID.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not assigned");
                        bSuccess = true;
                    }  
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigned");
                        bSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    bSuccess = false;
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        };

        //Second type to check
        if (_entity is tblDevice)
        {
            var _device = _entity as tblDevice;
            await _context.Entry(_entity).ReloadAsync().ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                if (!x.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var query = from c in _context.tblDevices
                                where c.ID.Equals(_device.ID)
                                select c;

                    if (query.Single().COID.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not assigned");
                        bSuccess = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Assigned");
                        bSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    bSuccess = false;
                }

            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        };


        //Third type to check ....
        //Fourth type to check ....

        return bSuccess;
    }
```

Does anyone see a better solution to the problem?

Comment: Why not pick the ID instead of the entity? All you need is the Set and the ID. Just pass those as parameters, and you should be fine.

Comment: Because the entity I am passing can be from different tables. So I am not sure how to program a generic method. Also the ID parameter is only accessible if I am targeting a specific table.

Comment: Is `COID` a generic property for your entities?

Comment: Also if ID is the primary key, I think it would be better if you use _dbSet.Find(ID), this would search on the PrimaryKey.

Comment: Yes, each entity has a COID (Check out ID)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common query for multiple similar entity types in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339968/common-query-for-multiple-similar-entity-types-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed arekzyla's solution to make my tables inheret tblBase.
However, since I have a database-first model it was not possible to modify my model through code (not sure if this is possible?)

I managed to get what I was looking for thanks to arekzyla, but with less linq queries involved, I am casting my entities as TblBase which is a class containing ID and COID (common table properties.)

```
public static async Task<bool> IsEntityCheckedOut(ProjectEntities _context, object _entity)
    {
        var bCheckedOut = false;
        await _context.Entry(_entity).ReloadAsync().ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            if (!x.IsFaulted)
            {
                var _baseentity = _entity as TblBase;
                if (_baseentity.COID.GetValueOrDefault() != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Assigned");
                    bCheckedOut = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not Assigned");
                }
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        return bCheckedOut;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make base abstract class for both tblLine and tblDevice containing at least properties COID and Id.

```
public abstract class TblBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int COID { get; set; }

    //other common properties
}

public class TblLine : TblBase
{
    // properties
}

public class TblDevice : TblBase
{
    // properties
}
```

So in your context you will have:

```
public DbSet<TblBase> TblBases { get; set; }
```

You have to set inheritance to TPC (Table-per-Concrete-Type) for both classes:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TblLine>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("tblLines");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<TblDevice>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties();
    m.ToTable("tblDevices");
});
```

Then you can use context.TblBases to query data.

Comment: Hi arekyla, I appreciate your answer. It has assisted me in finding another solution. Because I did not follow a code-first approach it seems I cannot make manual model changes.

Comment: @Pieterkii I think when you use database first approach it should also work because the model is not changed (all the properties are the same), classes are mapped to concrete tables and only the query is different

Comment: I get an exception for trying to use _context.TblBases .where(linq expression)                                                                                "The entity type TblBase is not part of the model for the current context."

Comment: @Pieterkii have you added mappings to protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) ?

Comment: @arekylza yes, I added the following above the other mappings also:             modelBuilder.Entity<TblBase>().ToTable("TblBase");

Comment: @Pieterkii Make sure that base class is abstract it should work. However your new solution looks good